# Facebook login on page app using php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

I have prepared a Facebook login for an application installed in page, the problem is when I click on the "login" button on the page it redirect to a blank white page, without connecting, 
but when i open the app with the direct link "https://example.com/my-app", the login is working good without any problems and the user keep being connected after approving the app;

I am working with :

- codeigniter 3.0
- Facebook PHP SDK v4
- PHP 5.4
- Facebook Scope : public_profile, email

Comment: You’re probably trying to call the login dialog inside the iframe, which is not possible, you have to call it in the top window instance. But you should consider using the JS SDK’s `FB.login` method instead, it makes for a much nicer user experience.

Comment: Ya i tried with the JS SDK, and its working, i just see it more secure by adding the Facebook session using php, thank you @CBroe

Comment: The JS SDK and the PHP SDK are perfectly capable of working together – once you logged the user in client-side, the PHP SDK can pick that up on the next request.

Comment: So we use the JS SDK to connect the app with the user by showing the dialog, then the PHP SDK do the rest, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Add `target="_top"` to your login link in the iframe to make it redirect to the login page in the top window instance.